# Lower bound on the size of the universe, if closed

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, spacetime, universe, observable-universe

As the measurements show the flatness of our universe is approximately 1 but the measurements are with a slight error. If we assume that the flatness is greater than 1 but still within the error of measurements, how big would the universe be?

I understand that the total size of the universe would thus be much bigger than the visible universe, but how much?

Comment: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/33897/based-off-of-the-study-that-found-the-universe-has-a-positive-curvature-how-big

Comment: If cosmic inflation happened, the entire universe is *vastly* larger than the observable part, even if both are finite.

Comment: @G.Smith Why would the inflation change the size ratio of the observable universe to the entire uninverse?

Comment: @safesphere I can’t explain why, but [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observable_universe) says “According to the theory of cosmic inflation ... if it is assumed that inflation began about $10^{−37}$ seconds after the Big Bang, then with the plausible assumption that the size of the universe before the inflation occurred was approximately equal to the speed of light times its age, that would suggest that at present the entire universe's size is at least $3\times 10^{23}$ times the radius of the observable universe.” The source is one of Guth’s books.

Comment: @safesphere What I can explain is that one of the motivations for inflation was solving the “[flatness problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatness_problem)”. It does so by making the observable universe a small fraction of the entire universe, so that it appears to be flat just like a small part of the Earth’s surface appears to be flat.